# How would I PM a user after I have banned/kicked them?

Tags: javascript, discord

So I am trying to have my Discord bot (coded in discord.js) PM the user that I have kicked and/or banned. But I keep getting an error back that says that the bot can not PM that user.

I have already tried doing **`kUser.send('Blah Blah Blah')`**. with ***kUser*** being the user that is being kicked

````
const kUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));

const reason = args.join(" ").slice(22);

kUser.send(`You've been kick from the server due to the following reason:\n${reason}`);```
````

Comment: Why not just message them first and kick them after?

Comment: I tried that as well, but forgot to mention that

Comment: So the problem is not that the user is banned or kicked but not contactable for some other reason.

Comment: If the user has DMs blocked for the server the bot won't be able to send them a message. That said, like mentioned above, ideally you'd send the message and then kick them because the bot can't message persons it doesn't share a server with.